# Read/plot custom extension files

Tags: python, file-io, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have set of pre executed files and they are not with a known extensions like `.txt` or `.csv` or `.dat`. They have extensions from the process names like time0.1 time0.01 ans so on. When i am trying to read them and plot specific column against log of 10 power. I can plot the graph when I copy the content of the file to a new file and extension .txt but I have like 100+ such files and want to read them all together and plot them on one canvas only. I get error as file not found. I cannot copy paste every file into a new file when I have to plot them. Is it possible have simple way where I can load the txt in which ever format it is and pick a particular column to plot. I also tried using `usecols=(0,1)` with `numpy.loadtxt()` but everytime it shows "`file not found error`". I did search for the error and everywhere what suggestions I see I make the necessary changes but still its the same error.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import*
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

for fname in ('threshold0.1_time10', 'threshold0.01_time10', 'threshold0.001_time10', 'threshold0.0001_time10', 'threshold0_time10'):
    data = np.loadtxt(fname)
    #X=data[0:,]
    Y=data[:,2]
    plt.plot(Y,':ro')
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Input:

```
1 18683 0.0457805581489
2 3519 0.00862290767681
3 101048 0.247606585657
4 284849 0.697989948517
```

Every input file has these three columns and I am interested in only `col[2]`

Error

```
File "read_format.py", line 9, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt("fname", usecols=(0,1,2))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 690, in loadtxt
    fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'threshold0_time10'
```

Comment: So what is the problem?  File extensions are more fro human use than computer use.

Comment: @tcaswell Updated few more details

Comment: suspect you just need to include more path information.

Comment: @tcaswell Everything is in same directory

Comment: your traceback does not match your code.

Comment: Your error message shows that obviously it only fails for one of the files. Does it work if you cancel this one for testing and go with the rest? If the rest is working, you can start struggeling ojn including that file...